# Add classes via jquery

Tags: jquery, html

So here's the deal, I have a bunch of thumbnails, each linking to my projects page including an id. ie:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="page.html#projectOne">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="awesome image" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My projects page looks like this:

```
    <div class="projects" id="projectOne">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="projects" id="projectTwo">
        ...
    </div>
```

and so on. All these divs are standard on **`display: none`** through the projects class. 
I've also made a class, called`active`, that has `display: block`.

So I've tried to add this class via jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(showUp){
    $("ul li a").on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass( "active" );
    });
});
```

This however does not seem to work since the code is not adding the class to my div.

Comment: What exactly do you think `this` is referring to?

Comment: They are adding class to Anchor element. To which `this` is referring

Comment: `page.html#projectOne` would cause a page redirect, so any change to the current page DOM would be irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the element being clicked, in your case, its the anchor element. I noticed you have the div ID's stored after a hashtag in your anchor href, so you can do:

```
$("ul li a").on('click', function() {
    //Remove any other .active class
    $(".projects").removeClass("active");

    var divID = $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];
    $("#" + divID).addClass("active");

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Might want to add logic to remove the `active` class from all `.project` elements when link is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the comment tymeJV. It does indeed make sense that I was referring to a wrong element. Your answer however hasn't resolved my issue though. It's still not adding the `active` class to my `div`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("ul, li, a").addClass("active");
        });
```

Comment: The OP is not wanting to add the `active` class to the `ul`, `li`, or `a`.